# Time complexity ordering a vector of size $n$ vs $m$ vectors of size $m_i$ such that $\sum_{i}{m_i}=n$

Tags: time-complexity

If one has a vector of size $n$, one can sort it in $O(n \log{n})$. If one has $m$ vectors of size $m_i$ each, such that $\sum_{i}{m_i}=n$, what's the total time complexity to sort all of them? I belive it's still $O(n \log{n})$ but can't formalize.

Comment: Hint: sort each vector, and use $m_i \le n$ to bound the resulting time complexity.

Comment: (Follow-on question: If $m = m_i = \sqrt n$, is it possible to give a tighter bound? What if $m_i = \log n$, $m_i = 1$?)